# Worksheet Comaparison Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am dealing with code which is reading two worksheets. The first WS contains all of my desired categories but not the desired values associated with them. The second WS contains my desired categories and values but also contains undesired categories and values. I want to write a macro that will consolidate all of the data into the format provided on the far right.

DA is desired category A, RA is Random category A

[Picture of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6K1H.png)

Here is the macro I wrote to deal with this. It works for a couple 100 rows or so and then suddenly stops working...any ideas why?

```
Sub reader2()
Dim i As Long, w As Long, a As String, b As String, c As Long, d As Long 
'declare variables

i = 770 'set counters
w = 1163

Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Calc").Cells(i + 3, 4).Value)
'declare termination condition
a = Worksheets("Calc").Cells(i + 3, 4).Value 'set match value

Do Until a = b 'error nest loop
b = Worksheets("Sales data").Cells(w + 4, 5).Value 'value of b
If a = b Then 'match conditions
c = Worksheets("Sales data").Cells(w + 4, 7)
d = w
End If
w = w + 1 'goes down one more row every cycle
If w > 10000 Then Exit Do 'failsafe for value not existing
Loop

Cells(i + 3, 9).Value = c 'match value
i = i + 1 'iteration

If w > 10000 Then 'reset counter to last correct match
w = d
Cells(i + 3, 9).Value = "none" 'alert that no value found
End If

Loop
End Sub
```

For these examples VLOOKUP (thank you tiger) was used as proof that the values exist and the code failed.
VLOOKUP is the column on the right while macro is the left column

Example Error 1
[Ex 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYHy4.png) works for the fist non found value (100000000) and for a little after until it gives a series of non found values (100000000) when they exist and thier value is 0.

Comment: *then suddenly stops working* is very vague. Providing a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example will help us help you more effectively.

Comment: Do you really need a macro for this? It looks like it can be done with a simple [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: In your case, in sheet `Calc` cell i773, use this formula and copy down: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D774,'Sales Data'!$E$1166:$G$11166,3,FALSE),"none")`

Comment: Scott Holtzman, working on finding that for you

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I added an example to the original post. I have another one showing the code completely stop working.

Comment: @tigeravatar, the desired strings are repeated throughout the list but with different values representing them. Im looking at inventory from plants vs how much we sold and trying to get days of coverage. I have all the materials i want to look at in one worksheet and all the materials/values mixed with those i dont in the other. VLOOKUP would just pull the first match it got right?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman something also to note is that when I run the debugger and go through the process manually...it works. Only when running the whole thing does it start messing up